# Returning success and then restarting computer

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I'm integrating Jenkins with a bunch of stuff and im using powershell to do this. I have a script on a remote machine that is executed after a build is successful on jenkins. This script does a bunch of stuff and then will restart the machine.

What i need to do is:

1. Return to jenkins that the script was successful (meaning that it will end the job as SUCCESS)
2. Then restart the machine

So far i have not managed to send 'EXIT 0' to jenkins and then restart the machine. There's anyway to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Code example:

```
Write-Host "Code example"
Exit 0 #for jenkins success
Restart-Computer -Force
```

Comment: After the `Exit` keyword the script will not pass to the `Restart-Computer` part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will host a seperate command prompt that runs async from the powershell script and restarts the computer in 3 seconds, enough time for powershell to return the exit code to jenkins.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "cmd.exe" -ArgumentList '/c "timeout /t 3 /nobreak && shutdown -r -f -t 0"' -WindowStyle Hidden
Exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment by @Avshalom, your problem is that the `Exit` statement will unconditionally exit your script without ever executing the `Restart-Computer` command placed *after* it.

`Restart-Computer`, when executed locally, is *invariably asynchronous*, so your script will continue to execute, at least for a while.

You can therefore try to call `Restart-Computer` first, and `exit 0` afterwards:

```
Write-Host "Code example"
Restart-Computer -Force
exit 0 # for Jenkins success
```

However, there's no *guarantee* that control will return to Jenkins in time and that Jenkins itself will have time to process the successful exit before it is shut down itself.

You can improve the likelihood of that with a *delay*, via a separate, asynchronously launched PowerShell instance<sup>[1]</sup>, similar to the approach in [Evilcat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51714345/45375):

```
Write-Host "Code example"

# Asynchronously start a separate, hidden PowerShell instance 
# that sleeps for 5 seconds before initiating the shutdown.
Start-Process -WindowStyle Hidden powershell.exe -Args '-command',
  'Start-Sleep 5; Restart-Computer -Force'


exit 0 # for Jenkins success
```

This still isn't a fully robust solution, however; a fully robust solution requires changing your approach:

- Let your script indicate success only, without initiating a restart.
- Make Jenkins test for success and, if so, call another script that unconditionally initiates a shutdown.

---

<sup>[1] As Evilcat points out, using a *background job* with `Start-Job` does *not* work, because on exiting the calling PowerShell session with `exit` the background jobs are terminated too.</sup>